# CAML query with nonexistent field

Tags: sharepoint, caml

We need to have a web service that queries a sharepoint list using CAML, but we do not know what version of the list that we are using.  Version introduced a new field we want to use in the query if it is present, but just ignore that otherwise.  If I put it in the query on the old version, we get no results.  How should I check if the field exists before setting up the query?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that if you make the field nullable in the ViewFields, the query will work whether the field exists or not.

```
<FieldRef Name='Field1' Nullable='TRUE'/>
```